# How do I turn an Action<T> to a Compiled Expression or a DynamicMethod by generating IL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees, dynamicmethod

I am having to deal with maintaining a library which allows users to register a generic handler (`Action<T>`) against it and later on once it receives an event it goes through each of the registered handlers and passes them the event. To keep the question short, let us skip the reasons why it has been done this way.

Because of this design we have had to call `DynamicInvoke` when passing each event; This is proving quite slow and hence the need to either turn the delegates into a CompiledExpression or a DynamicMethod using IL generation. I have seen various examples of implementing this for PropertyGetters ([Matt Warren's excellent article](https://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/)) but I cannot get it to work with `Action<T>` where `T` can be both a ValueType or a ReferenceType.

Here's a current (slow) working example to play with (simplified for brevity):

```
void Main()
{
    var producer = new FancyEventProduder();
    var fancy = new FancyHandler(producer);
    
    fancy.Register<Base>(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    producer.Publish(new Child());  
}

public sealed class FancyHandler
{
    private readonly List<Delegate> _handlers;
    
    public FancyHandler(FancyEventProduder produer)
    {
        _handlers = new List<Delegate>();
        produer.OnMessge += OnMessage;
    }

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler) => _handlers.Add(handler);

    private void OnMessage(object sender, object payload)
    {
        Type payloadType = payload.GetType();
        foreach (Delegate handler in _handlers)
        {
            // this could be cached at the time of registration but has negligable impact
            Type delegParamType = handler.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
            if(delegParamType.IsAssignableFrom(payloadType))
            {
                handler.DynamicInvoke(payload);
            }           
        }
    }
}

public sealed class FancyEventProduder
{
    public event EventHandler<object> OnMessge;
    
    public void Publish(object payload) => OnMessge?.Invoke(this, payload);
}

public class Base { }
public sealed class Child : Base { }
```

Comment: You can't really escape from `if(delegParamType.IsAssignableFrom(payload.GetType())) handler.DynamicInvoke(payload);`, so I don't think you can do really fancy things

Comment: How so? I can still compile the expression at the time of registration and choose not to call it in the if statement, no?

Comment: What expression you want to generate? It isn't unclear. An expression is a like a piece of code that you write at runtime, but this piece of dynamical code still follows rules similar to C# (technically similar to IL language, but C# is a good proxy for IL). There still is strict parameter type checking inside this expression, like C#.

Comment: If you have a look at Matt's article or Jon Skeet's blog post referenced there it explains what I am trying to achieve here. In summary, the goal is to make DynamicInvoke faster.

Comment: Ok... We can try... I think it is a bad idea and it won't optimize anything... But we can try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is a good idea:

```
public sealed class FancyHandler
{
    private readonly List<Tuple<Delegate, Type, Action<object>>> _handlers = new List<Tuple<Delegate, Type, Action<object>>>();

    public FancyHandler(FancyEventProduder produer)
    {
        produer.OnMessge += OnMessage;
    }

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        _handlers.Add(Tuple.Create((Delegate)handler, typeof(T), BuildExpression(handler)));
    }

    private static Action<object> BuildExpression<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
        var casted = Expression.Convert(par, typeof(T));
        var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, casted);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(call, par);
        return exp.Compile();
    }

    private void OnMessage(object sender, object payload)
    {
        Type payloadType = payload.GetType();

        foreach (var handlerDelegate in _handlers)
        {
            // this could be cached at the time of registration but has negligable impact
            Type delegParamType = handlerDelegate.Item2;
                
            if (delegParamType.IsAssignableFrom(payloadType))
            {
                handlerDelegate.Item3(payload);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that some smaller ideas can be reused even without using expression trees: saving the `typeof(T)` instead of calling many times `handler.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType` for example.

Some test cases:

```
fancy.Register<Base>(x => Console.WriteLine($"Base: {x}"));
fancy.Register<Child>(x => Console.WriteLine($"Child: {x}"));
fancy.Register<object>(x => Console.WriteLine($"object: {x}"));
fancy.Register<long>(x => Console.WriteLine($"long: {x}"));
fancy.Register<long?>(x => Console.WriteLine($"long?: {x}"));
fancy.Register<int>(x => Console.WriteLine($"int: {x}"));
fancy.Register<int?>(x => Console.WriteLine($"int?: {x}"));

producer.Publish(new Base());
producer.Publish(new Child());
producer.Publish(5);
```

Full expression tree (the type check is moved INSIDE the expression tree, where the `as` is done instead of `IsAssignableFrom`)

```
public sealed class FancyHandler
{
    private readonly List<Action<object>> _handlers = new List<Action<object>>();

    public FancyHandler(FancyEventProduder produer)
    {
        produer.OnMessge += OnMessage;
    }

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        _handlers.Add(BuildExpression(handler));
    }

    private static Action<object> BuildExpression<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(object))
        {
            return (Action<object>)(Delegate)handler;
        }

        var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        Expression body;

        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            // We remove the nullable part of value types
            Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);

            var unbox = Expression.Unbox(par, typeof(T));
            body = Expression.IfThen(Expression.TypeEqual(par, type), Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, unbox));

            if (type != typeof(T))
            {
                // Nullable type
                // null with methods that accept nullable type: call the method
                body = Expression.IfThenElse(Expression.Equal(par, Expression.Constant(null)), Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(T))), body);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Imagine the resulting code will be:

            // (object par) => 
            // {
            //     if (par == null)
            //     {
            //         handler(null);
            //     }
            //     else
            //     {
            //         T local;
            //         local = par as T;
            //         if (local != null)
            //         {
            //             handler(local);
            //         }
            //     }
            // }

            var local = Expression.Variable(typeof(T));
                
            var typeAs = Expression.Assign(local, Expression.TypeAs(par, typeof(T)));

            var block = Expression.Block(new[]
            {
                local,
            },
            new Expression[]
            {
                typeAs,
                Expression.IfThen(Expression.NotEqual(typeAs, Expression.Constant(null)), Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, typeAs))
            });

            // Handling case par == null, call the method
            body = Expression.IfThenElse(Expression.Equal(par, Expression.Constant(null)), Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(handler.Target), handler.Method, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(T))), block);
        }

        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(body, par);
        return exp.Compile();
    }

    private void OnMessage(object sender, object payload)
    {
        foreach (var handlerDelegate in _handlers)
        {
            handlerDelegate(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

This version supports even `null`:

```
producer.Publish(null);
```

A third version, based on the idea of @BorisB, this version eskews the use of `Expression` and uses directly delegates. It should have a shorter warmup time (no `Expression` trees to be compiled). There is still has a minor reflection problem, but fortunately this problem is only present during the adding of new handlers (there is a comment that explains it).

```
public sealed class FancyHandler
{
    private readonly List<Action<object>> _handlers = new List<Action<object>>();

    public FancyHandler(FancyEventProduder produer)
    {
        produer.OnMessge += OnMessage;
    }

    public void Register<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            _handlers.Add(BuildExpressionValueType(handler));
        }
        else
        {
            // Have to use reflection here because the as operator requires a T is class
            // this check is bypassed by using reflection
            _handlers.Add((Action<object>)_buildExpressionReferenceTypeT.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(null, new[] { handler }));
        }
    }

    private static Action<object> BuildExpressionValueType<T>(Action<T> handler)
    {
        // We remove the nullable part of value types
        Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(T))
        {
            // Non nullable
            return (object par) =>
            {
                if (par is T)
                {
                    handler((T)par);
                }
            };
        }

        // Nullable type
        return (object par) =>
        {
            if (par == null || par is T)
            {
                handler((T)par);
            }
        };
    }

    private static readonly MethodInfo _buildExpressionReferenceTypeT = typeof(FancyHandler).GetMethod(nameof(BuildExpressionReferenceType), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static Action<object> BuildExpressionReferenceType<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(object))
        {
            return (Action<object>)(Delegate)handler;
        }

        return (object par) =>
        {
            if (par == null)
            {
                handler((T)par);
            }
            else
            {
                T local = par as T;

                if (local != null)
                {
                    handler(local);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void OnMessage(object sender, object payload)
    {
        foreach (var handlerDelegate in _handlers)
        {
            handlerDelegate(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! My benchmarks of handling 5 million events went from 3 seconds down to 50 milliseconds!

Comment: @MaYaN New version, full expression type... The type checking is moved INSIDE the expression tree.

Comment: I haven't done .Net in years, but couldn't `BuildExpression` be implemented simply as  `return delegate(object o) { handler.Invoke((T)o); }` so that the returned closure captures the exact `T`?

Comment: @BorisB. Probably yes :-) But when someone asks me for an Expression tree, I do love to write an Expression tree 

Comment: @xanatos you are on FIRE! The newer version shaved off a few more ms you have given me options now! Thank you.

Comment: @BorisB. Your solution is also very fast! actually only a few ms slower than the compiled Expression. I will need to do more testing to validate different use-cases.

Comment: @BorisB. Sadly your idea can't be expanded to do the type check internally. If I try to do `if (o is T)` it will refuse because `T` isn't always a `class`, and it isn't a check that is easy to bypass.

Comment: @MaYaN Third version based on BorisB idea, plus the type check INSIDE the delegate method.

Comment: @xanatos The 3rd version is throwing a NullRef ex in Register when `Registering<Base>` and publishing `Child`

Comment: @MaYaN Strange... it passes all the tests I have... As they say "works on my pc" :-) https://ideone.com/PU0fsq (and on Ideone)

Comment: Yes, problem was on my side, the newer version is even faster than the other versions!

Comment: The ability to move the type check logic inside provides a better perf; I do have use-cases though where I will need to know the result of the typecheck, it would be super useful if I could get the result of that type check out but I guess in that case, `Action<object>` would need to be turned into `Func<object, bool>` which is not bad actually, alternatively I could just do a type check anyway even though I know the expression will also do it internally.

Comment: @MaYaN As they say in certain math books "changing the return type is left as a simple exercise for the students" :-)

Comment: @xanatos, indeed! I was merely thinking outloud, thank you for your help on this, much appreciated.